# How to identify scripts that are not used before the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, pagespeed

Reading the [Google recommendations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?csw=1#DeferLoadingJS) of how to speed-up the page loading:

> Deferring loading of JavaScript functions **that are not called at
>   startup** reduces the initial download size, allowing other resources
>   to be downloaded in parallel, and speeding up execution and rendering
>   time.
>
> ## Details
>
> Like stylesheets, scripts must be downloaded, parsed, and executed
>   before the browser can begin to render a web page. Again, even if a
>   script is contained in an external file that is cached, processing of
>   all elements below the script is blocked until the browser loads the
>   code from disk and executes it. However, for some browsers, the
>   situation is worse than for stylesheets: while JavaScript is being
>   processed, the browser blocks all other resources from being
>   downloaded. [...]
>
> For many script-intensive applications, the bulk of the JavaScript
>   code handles user-initiated events, such as mouse-clicking and
>   dragging, form entry and submission, hidden elements expansion, and so
>   on. All of these user-triggered events occur after the page is loaded
>   and the onload event is triggered. Therefore, much of the delay in the
>   "critical path" (the time to load the main page at startup) could be
>   avoided by deferring the loading of the JavaScript until it's actually
>   needed. While this "lazy" method of loading doesn't reduce the total
>   JS payload, it can significantly reduce the number of bytes needed to
>   load the initial state of the page, and allows the remaining bytes to
>   be loaded asynchronously in the background.
>
> To use this technique, **you should first identify all of the JavaScript
>   functions that are not actually used by the document before the onload
>   event**. For any file containing more than 25 uncalled functions, move
>   all of those functions to a separate, external JS file.

## Question

**How to identify that scripts, that are not used when loading?**
Say, I was charged to optimize a web solution that I see for the first time and that uses a lot of scripts that I am not aware about what they are doing. Is there a way to monitor and separate the "lazy" and "early" scripts?

Comment: Add a unique `console.log` output to the top of each function, a name or a number, and check which ones aren't used. Then one more log at the top of `$(document).ready`. In practice, however, Google's recommendations are more relevant to large JS applications than to small enhancements like you're probably using.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web optimization and not actual programming.  This question is much more suited for [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: web optimization is not programming? how can I optimize without programming?